# Javascript D3.js d3.json() function not accepting valid json, what to do to use it the same as d3.csv?

Tags: javascript, json, csv, d3.js, histogram

Learning d3.js I was building a histogram with raw data from a .csv file like this,

CSV

```
x,y
2,16
3,18
5,18
12,19
```

D3

```
d3.csv("data.csv", function (data) {

var map = data.map(function (i) {
    return parseFloat(i.y);
})

var histogram = d3.layout.histogram()
    .bins(4)
    (map)
```

...etc. This was my initial call and it works.

Putting the same data in a valid json format like this,

```
[{"y":["16","18","18","19"],"x":["2","3","5","12"]}]
```

Calling the data like this doesn't work,

```
d3.json("data.json", function (json) {

var map = data.map(function (i) {
    return parseFloat(i.y);
})

var histogram = d3.layout.histogram()
    .bins(4)
    (map)
```

How can I get d3.js interpret the .json file in the same manner as the original .csv format so that the code that I have to change is minimal. Is this possible at all? The documentation I read is really confusing to me and does not seem to work with my example. The best tutorials on Youtube use .csv and not json. I need to use json.

Comment: what results do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this data for your json file:

```
[{"x":"2","y":"16"}, {"x":"3","y":"18"}, {"x":"5","y":"18"}, {"x":"12","y":"19"}]
```

You could also get rid of the `parseFloat(i.y)` (just return `i.y`) if you specify your data in number instead of string. CSV values are forced into strings while JSON can have numbers.

*EDIT:* change the first line to: `d3.json("data.json", function (error, data) {`. Note the parameter names. Your code should work after this.

Comment: That kind of helps. However is giving me "undefined" or "null" when accessing the map method.

Comment: Try changing function (json) to function (data)

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. There's support in d3 for callback functions that expect the `data` parameter, per the last function definition at https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/84f4a62c019b4f591383ccce6a6582da1a384f9a/src/xhr/xhr.js

Comment: @rebHelium,  can't get this to work on jsfiddle, but I've confirmed that d3.json works as described in this answer by establishing both a data.csv and data.json file and using my local web server to confirm. Have you tried reducing your code to the very minimum by just writing the data argument to the console? Have you looked at your JavaScript console to see if there are any errors (e.g. associated with the retrieving from the URI)?

Comment: Alright, Thach Mai was right about the format. I also had problems with the "map" and other stuff in the code. This video helped me nail  it down. Thanks for the help! http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2S1AbEWX85o